# Running cron job on localhost using Whenever gem

Tags: ruby, cron, sinatra, whenever

Currently I have a Ruby and Sinatra project in which I am trying to automate a task. I have followed all the [installation steps](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for the Whenever gem and written a function in my `schedule.rb` file that looks like this:

```
set :output, "./cron_log.log"


every 1.minutes do
    command "ruby ./scripts/my_script.rb"
end
```

My project will eventually be deployed to a remote server, but I do not have access to that at the moment. Instead, I am testing it all by running it on my local machine using the command `bundle exec shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 -p 9393`. When I run it, none of the functions in my `schedule.rb` file are run. I ran a test by putting `require './scripts/my_script.rb'` at the top of the `schedule.rb` file. Whenever I run `bundle exec whenever`, that outside function will execute, but not the function inside the `every` block. I figured maybe it only works on a live server, so I ran the `bundle exec shotgun -o 0.0.0.0 -p 9393` command to start my server on localhost but nothing in the `schedule.rb` file was called, including the outside function. I tried putting the command `system("bundle exec whenever")` in my authentication file, which gets activated every time a user loads the home page of my website, and the outside function in `schedule.rb` *does* get called, but the `every` function does not. Even if it did work like this, I don't want the file to get called every single time a user accesses the home page.

I also tried putting `require './config/schedule'` in the authentication file and that just completely breaks the website and gives this error message:

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading config.ru
NoMethodError: undefined method `every' for main:Object
```

Here is part of the output when running the `crontab -l` command:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /file_path_redacted/config/schedule.rb at: 2022-10-21 18:50:21 -0500
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby ./scripts/my_script.rb >> ./cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /file_path_redacted/config/schedule.rb at: 2022-10-21 18:50:21 -0500
```

So, my question is this: **How and when is the `schedule.rb` file supposed to get called? And is it important that I deploy the project to the remote server for the cron job to work? Again, it is not possible for me to deploy it, as it must be fully working before being deployed. If it is possible to run on localhost, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: The very next sections (after "Installation") in the documentation you linked above explain how to use `whenever` :) You are not supposed to call or require `schedule.rb`, you are supposed to use `whenever` CLI to update the crontab. If you did everything properly `crontab -l` will show the scheduled tasks...

Comment: @Konstantin I have updated my post and I believe it addresses your comment.

Comment: So what's the question then? You see the entry in your user's crontab generated by `whenever` CLI. If the cron daemon is up and running, this task will be executed according to the schedule. Isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov It doesn't run when my program is running. None of the functions in my `schedule.rb` file run when my program is running. Maybe my cron daemon is not running? I'm not sure.